# Ajax wont work if wrapped around a jquery on submit function

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Hello I am trying to activate my ajax when I submit a form. However it wont work if I place the ajax logic inside of a function like so, however it works if I remove the on submit function. How can I get this to work?

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function () {
    if($("#slct1").val() === "") {
        console.log("Form not submitted");
    } else {
    $("#myForm").submit();
    $("#loading").show();
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/qa-hub/tools/wss_qa_tool/api/data",
          dataType: "json"
          }).then(addData)
                function addData(data) {
                // console.log(data.recordset[0]);
                console.log(Object.keys(data.recordset[0]));

                Object.keys(data.recordset[0]).forEach(function(column) {
                    $("#theadRow").append("<th>" + column + "</th>");
                });

                let master = "";

                for(var i = 1; i < data.recordset.length; i++) {
                for( var key in data.recordset[i]) {
                    var current = "<td>" + data.recordset[i][key] + "</td>";
                        master = master + current;

                }
                $("#tBody").append("<tr>" + master + "</tr>");
                master = "";
                }
                $('#myTable').DataTable()
            }
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: does your form tag has a action?

Comment: Yes it has an action <form id="myForm" action="/qa-hub/tools/wss_qa_tool/sql/data" method="POST">

Comment: remove that, when you click submit, it calls that action, not the ajax,  and comment this in code  $("#myForm").submit(); , it looks like its going in loop. call submit inside submit

Comment: Another solution if you are submitting via a submit button is change your submit button to type="button" and add a class. Then write the ajax to happen ONCLICK of that button class.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedSunny that worked Any chance you are familiar with using node.js and express?

Comment: not much, i just used it for one project,